# How to call the swift view controller from javascript click action?

Tags: ios, swift, cordova, swift3, cordova-plugins

Actually I am having my old project using Cordova in iOS 
but I have newly created project (updated version) is in Swift 3 (native). I need to combine these two  in single app.
so, I have used this pod files to load the Cordova HTML files

```
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-webview-ios
```

that pod is working fine in Cordova projects but what I
need was to call the swift view controller from javascript click action..?

I also raised the issue in GitHub pages also

```
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-webview-ios/issues/23
```

is it possible to load the swift view controller from the javascript click action ?

Usually most of the guys used WKWebview but i Used Cordova so, cordova already have an WKWebview message handler, so mainly i need to use how to access that from cordova html files..

please tell if any know about it..!

Comment: yes @Luzo got it...

Comment: for objective-C implementation, check with this answer with full explaination at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26202904/wkuserscript-not-working/42501756?noredirect=1#comment75317548_42501756

Comment: yes i known about WKscript meassge handler but i need it from the cordova app.! which i installed from the pod @AnuragSoni... And i got the answer for that dude.. what i do was i just add the extra method in the objective c console longer file and i get the response from the swift class file. so i early call the swift viewcontroller.. Thanks dude..